# EKEvent accept event invtation

Tags: ios, eventkit, ekevent, ekeventkit, ekeventstore

I wonder how can I set accept/may be/decline participant status for an `EKEvent` for which current user has been invited?

I can check the participant set but `EKEvent` found nothing for which I can set its status.

Comment: There is an `EKEvent.status` property but it doesn't appear to work. Unaccepted meetings are set to `confirmed` and meetings that only contain one person are set to `none`.

Answer (score 0):

Status is maintained per each EKParticipant (not on the EKEvent itself), but you can't set it programmatically: `[EKParticipant participantStatus]` is read only. Per the Apple docs,

> Event Kit cannot add participants to an event nor change participant
>   information.

The closest approximation of this would be to bring up the event using EventKitUI components and allow the user to update the event as they see fit.

Comment: Hi mygzi! Using EKEventViewController with the EventKitUI components doesn't work for me. The layout appears but the buttons (accept/maybe/decline) don't perform any action in the calendar. Do you have maybe an alternative? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170415/how-to-accept-decline-ekevent-invitation